# Implementing Timeout on BackgroundTransferService transfer request - Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am using BackgroundTransferService to download a file from the internet.

pseudo code goes something like this:

```
BackgroundTransferRequest transferRequest = new BackgroundTransferRequest(transferUri);
transferRequest.Method = "GET";
transferRequest.Tag = "myTag";
transferRequest.TransferPreferences = TransferPreferences.AllowCellularAndBattery;
BackgroundTransferService.Add(transferRequest);
```

after this, i add an event handler to handle the transfer when it is completed.
I am only using TransferStatusChanged event handler, not TransferProgressChanged

```
transferRequests = BackgroundTransferService.Requests;
transferRequests.Last().TransferStatusChanged += new EventHandler<BackgroundTransferEventArgs>(transfer_TransferStatusChanged);
```

under transfer_TransferStatusChanged() i do whatever i want to do with my downloaded file, or handle the failed situations (404 etc).

The problem is that my downloads go on for indefinite time if there is no 404 response from the server (for example when there is no such server, eg. www.googlea.com/myfilename). I want to implement a timeout for such scenario .. how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in support for such a scenario. You'll have to build in the timeout support yourself.

Be careful of transfering large files though as the transfer could be done in parts and over a very large period of time, depending on connectivity and battery charge level.

Of course, you may want to add a check that a file exists before making the transfer request and if you have any control over the server you should make sure that the correct responses are being sent too.